# Les Paul and Fender Stratocaster

Tags: guitar-hero

Does the fender stratocaster for rock band sync with the guitar hero 5 game on PS3? I am not sure if it is compatible.

Answer (score 6):

A compatibility table can be found on the [**Guitar Hero Wiki**](http://guitarhero.wikia.com/wiki/Compatibility)

There are also these charts:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]